# How do I specify two different background sources for mobile and desktop version respectively through same molecule's mixin in index.pug content?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, pug

I am using the **pug** templating engine to design the front-end of my website, and would want to make it responsive (desktop and mobile compatible), however, I have **different background images for the desktop and mobile views respectively**, and would like to know of a way to specify the different sources of background images for the same component within a mixin in JSON format. Here is the code where I am calling the jcfcards mixin:

```
block content
   .flexboxcontainer
       +jcfbanner
       +jcfcards({"src": "/assets/images/Letter-J.png", "text":"Career Map"})
       +jcfcards({"src": "/assets/images/Letter-C.png", "text":"Competencies"})
       +jcfcards({"src": "/assets/images/Letter-F.png", "text":"Learning Roadmap"})
```

Here is the code for the jcfcards mixin:

```
mixin jcfcards(spec)
  - spec = spec || {}
  - spec.__class = spec.__class || ''

  div(style=`background-image:url('${spec.src}')`).jcfcardtitle(class=spec.__class)&attributes(attributes)
    if spec.text == "Career Map"
      p.careerMap= spec.text
    else
      p= spec.text
    .icon-long-right
```

If there is any other way I can tackle this problem, I would highly appreciate any inputs on that as well. :)

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code. Paste your code here.

Comment: 1. Below is the code for my index.pug content block where I am setting the background image via the mixins as shown.
`block content .flexboxcontainer
        +jcfbanner
        +jcfcards({"src": "/assets/images/Letter-J.png", "text":"Career Map"})
        +jcfcards({"src": "/assets/images/Letter-C.png", "text":"Competencies"})`
        
2. Below is the code of my molecule mixin where it sets the background image

`mixin jcfcards(spec)
  - spec = spec || {}
  - spec.__class = spec.__class || ''
  div(style=`background-image:url('${spec.src}')`)
      p= spec.text`

Comment: Edit your question to include that code. Not a comment.